# Truncate string after specific character length using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am getting below id from api,

```
F4EF9B435R4T9234FGHDAE34JH5TT4
```

I need to truncate this text to next line after exact 18 characters like this,

```
F4EF9B435R4T9234FG
HDAE34JH5TT4
```

I have tried giving  `maxWidth` but sometimes it is getting truncated after 18 chracters or 17 charachters.

Comment: unless you are using a fix width font, different characters are different widths. Put a Zero Width Space at the character break point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ch` unit to truncate string after specific character length.

```css
div {
            width: 18ch;
            background: #eee;
            word-break: break-all;
            font-family: monospace;
        }
```

```html
<div>F4EF9B435R4T9234FGHDAE34JH5TT4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  width: 145px;
  background: #eee;
  word-break: break-all;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div>F4EF9B435R4T9234FGHDAE34JH5TT4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution using CSS is as below using `max-inline-size` :

```css
#test{
  max-inline-size: 20ch;
  word-break:break-all;
  font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">F4EF9B435R4T9234FGHDAE34JH5TT4</div>
```

Adjust the `max-inline-size` value in `ch` based on the `font-size` value.

If possible, you can achieve the same using javascript also, like in the below code:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("test").innerText;
var i = 0;
var ns = "";
while (i < a.length) {
  ns += a.substr(i, i + 18) + "\n";
  i = i + 18;
}
document.getElementById("test").innerText = ns;
```

```html
<div id="test">F4EF9B435R4T9234FGHDAE34JH5TT4</div>
```